# Failed to install pgaudit in default postgresql version

Tags: postgresql

When I try to install `pgaudit` in postgresql that Discourse provides by default, I got a failure messages like below:

```
<Error Messages>
root@07f8d9674261:/pgaudit#  make check USE_PGXS=1
Makefile:16: /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.
root@07f8d9674261:/pgaudit# cd pgaudit/
```

Do you know why? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to not having installed the server development packages. For instance, on Debian/Ubuntu, the Makefile that is missing here is provided by the **postgresql-server-dev-11** package.

Run `apt install postgresql-server-dev-11` as root to install it.

```
$ dpkg -S pgxs.mk
postgresql-server-dev-11: /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk

$ apt show postgresql-server-dev-11
Package: postgresql-server-dev-11
Version: 11.5-1.pgdg18.04+1
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Source: postgresql-11
Maintainer: Debian PostgreSQL Maintainers <team+postgresql@tracker.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 5 190 kB
Depends: clang-6.0, libpq-dev (>= 11~~), llvm-6.0-dev, postgresql-common (>= 142~), libc6 (>= 2.14)
Breaks: postgresql-server-dev-all (<< 181~)
Homepage: http://www.postgresql.org/
Download-Size: 933 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
Description: development files for PostgreSQL 11 server-side programming
 Header files for compiling SSI code to link into PostgreSQL's backend; for
 example, for C functions to be called from SQL.
 .
 This package also contains the Makefiles necessary for building add-on
 modules of PostgreSQL, which would otherwise have to be built in the
 PostgreSQL source-code tree.
 .
 PostgreSQL is an object-relational SQL database management system.
```